# How to get class names in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python-3.6, svm

I’m a beginner in ML, I built a SVM model to classify some inputs.
I used panda to read my dataset. The classification results are printed as indexes that each one of them is correspond to the name of the labels (classes) in my dataset. How can I convert these indexes to their names (string) ?

for example I have three classes : [Question,General,Info], but when I try to classify an input, the result is one of these numbers: [0,1,2]
I want to convert these numbers to the names of the classes I have.

here is a part of my code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("classes.csv",encoding='utf-16' )


Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data['input'],data['Class'],test_size=0.3,random_state=None)
```

`Test_Y` and `Train_Y` are lists of numbers (classes) , each number is referred to one class, how do I know what each number represents?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is: your model is working as expected. Most of the time, it'll output a probability for each label. So, if your model outputs something like `[0.1, 0.1, 0.8]`, it means the sample you're classifiying has 80% to belong to the label in position 2. If you pass all labels in the order you indicated in your question, that is, `[question, general, info]`, it means this sample belongs to the class `info`. Observe the order is important here and you need to ensure that when you're feeding the model in your code.

Therefore, to output a string instead of a number, you need to get the number outputted by the model and check the label in a list or dictionary containing this relationship. Using as an example a list:

```
labels_str = ['question', 'general', 'info']

# preds is a np.array containing the probabilities
preds = model(some_sample)

# this function returns the position of the max value in the array
pos_pred = preds.argmax() 

print ("The label for this sample is {}".format(labels_str[pos_pred])
```

Did you get the idea?

Comment: Thank you, but the problem that I don't know the order of the lables, it is not the same as the order in my dataset. Also, whenever I add new samples in the dataset, this order changes. So, is there another way rather than checking the order by myself?

Comment: Well, I don't how you're coding that, but you must control it to use any ML model. Before sending those data to your model, you need to clean this data to keep the same order, otherwise, you may misclassify the samples.

Comment: O.K. Thank you..!